# Moving "templates" folder in EE5

Tags: templates, ee, ee5

Do you have any alternatives for "tmpl_file_basepath" used in EE2 (it looks like this function has been deleted from EE3 version)? I wish to move "templates" folder above root but cannot find any solution yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are clear instructions on how to move not just the templates but the whole of the system folder above the HTML root in the [EE documentation](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/installation/best-practices.html#moving-the-system-directory-above-webroot).

HTH